# What conditions are associated with more intense feelings and stronger reactions to stimuli?

Tags: terminology, abnormal-psychology, emotion

What conditions are associated with more intense feelings and stronger reactions to stimuli?

i.e., where someone may normally feel small amounts of happiness, pleasure, sadness, grief, etc., someone with this condition would just have these feelings heightened and then act in a way proportional to the perceived level of sensation.

Comment: We tend to discourage "self-help" (I realize it's not for you, but still, it's in the same spirit) questions on this site, at least partially because the process of diagnosis is complex and depends on a lot of factors.  If you think these symptoms are not being addressed in your friend's care, talk to her about it, and she can refer the information to her provider.

Comment: Yeah we did talk about it and she actually really wanted me to post this question because she feels as if she is not getting an accurate diagnosis from her providers.

Comment: Well, that doesn't change anything regarding the site's position, unfortunately.  I wish we could help, but she'd be far better off getting advice from someone that is licensed to provide that care.

Comment: Thanks for thinking of asking your question here. However, another aspect of what we call "self-help" questions is that they tend to be specific to a particular person's situation. It might be possible to edit your question so that it is not embedded in your friend's circumstances. I.e., you could ask about the general phenomena. In essence, questions tend to be closed when they appear to request diagnoses to a particular person's situation.

Comment: @ChuckSherrington I've attempted to edit the question to make it plural "conditions" and prevent the question being concerned with a specific person's situation. I did this rather large edit, as it was either that or the question would be closed. Do you think it should still be closed? and Rob, is the modified question still of any value to you?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim It's better for me, I had thought about doing the same, though I got the impression that Robert was looking for a particular diagnosis (or diagnoses) for his friend more than general information.  We can see if it's still of value to him, as you proposed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit I was actually thinking of doing something like that so that saves me some time :)